# Visual Studio for Mac broken

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to open different Xamarin Solutions that worked before, e.g. the ones from https://github.com/xamarin/dev-days-labs (before vs update), now when I try to open the solution, I get the following fatal exception:

[image: Exception 1]

[image: Exception 2]

Ide.log says:

ERROR [2017-11-15 08:37:44Z]:ERROR [2017-11-15 08:37:44Z]: Error while

trying to load the project /Users/hoppentt/Documents/Projects/XamarinDevDays/dev-days-labs/Demos/app-tasks/DevDaysTasks.iOS/DevDaysTasks.iOS.csproj
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MonoDevelop.CSharp.Project.CSharpProject' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem.MonoDevelopWorkspace' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Type Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.CaseCorrection.VisualBasicCaseCorrectionService has invalid vtable method slot 6 with method none
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.RuntimeType:GetPropertiesByName_native (System.RuntimeType,intptr,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,bool)
  at System.RuntimeType.GetPropertiesByName (System.String name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Boolean icase, System.RuntimeType reflectedType) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:516 
  at System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyCandidates (System.String name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Type[] types, System.Boolean allowPrefixLookup) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:2881 
  at System.RuntimeType.GetProperties (System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:3089 
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetRuntimeProperties (System.Type type) [0x00006] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/RuntimeReflectionExtensions.cs:25 
  at System.Composition.TypedParts.Discovery.TypeInspector+d__7.MoveNext () [0x00030] in <9aac21a4a3f24063b2b8b59143acddfc>:0 
  at System.Composition.TypedParts.Discovery.TypeInspector+d__5.MoveNext () [0x000dc] in <9aac21a4a3f24063b2b8b59143acddfc>:0 
  at System.Composition.TypedParts.Discovery.TypeInspector.InspectTypeForPart (System.Reflection.TypeInfo type, System.Composition.TypedParts.Discovery.DiscoveredPart& part) [0x00061] in <9aac21a4a3f24063b2b8b59143acddfc>:0 
  at System.Composition.TypedParts.TypedPartExportDescriptorProvider..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] types, System.Composition.Convention.AttributedModelProvider attributeContext) [0x00037] in <9aac21a4a3f24063b2b8b59143acddfc>:0 
  at System.Composition.Hosting.ContainerConfiguration.CreateContainer () [0x00042] in <9aac21a4a3f24063b2b8b59143acddfc>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef.MefHostServices.Create (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] assemblies) [0x0001e] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem.MonoDevelopWorkspace..cctor () [0x001f9] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem/MonoDevelopWorkspace.cs:121 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MonoDevelop.CSharp.ProjectSearchCategory.Init () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/CSharpBinding/MonoDevelop.CSharp/ProjectSearchCategory.cs:53 
  at MonoDevelop.CSharp.Project.CSharpProject.get_TargetRuntime () [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/CSharpBinding/MonoDevelop.CSharp.Project/CSharpProjectExtension.cs:56 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:661 
 Error while trying to load the project /Users/hoppentt/Documents/Projects/XamarinDevDays/dev-days-labs/Demos/app-tasks/DevDaysTasks.Droid/DevDaysTasks.Droid.csproj
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MonoDevelop.CSharp.Project.CSharpProject' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem.MonoDevelopWorkspace' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Type Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.CaseCorrection.VisualBasicCaseCorrectionService has invalid vtable method slot 6 with method none
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.RuntimeType:GetPropertiesByName_native (System.RuntimeType,intptr,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,bool)
  at System.RuntimeType.GetPropertiesByName (System.String name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Boolean icase, System.RuntimeType reflectedType) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:516 
  at System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyCandidates (System.String name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Type[] types, System.Boolean allowPrefixLookup) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:2881 
  at System.RuntimeType.GetProperties (System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:3089 
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetRuntimeProperties (System.Type type) [0x00006] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/RuntimeReflectionExtensions.cs:25 
  at System.Composition.TypedParts.Discovery.TypeInspector+d__7.MoveNext () [0x00030] in <9aac21a4a3f24063b2b8b59143acddfc>:0 
  at System.Composition.TypedParts.Discovery.TypeInspector+d__5.MoveNext () [0x000dc] in <9aac21a4a3f24063b2b8b59143acddfc>:0 
  at System.Composition.TypedParts.Discovery.TypeInspector.InspectTypeForPart (System.Reflection.TypeInfo type, System.Composition.TypedParts.Discovery.DiscoveredPart& part) [0x00061] in <9aac21a4a3f24063b2b8b59143acddfc>:0 
  at System.Composition.TypedParts.TypedPartExportDescriptorProvider..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] types, System.Composition.Convention.AttributedModelProvider attributeContext) [0x00037] in <9aac21a4a3f24063b2b8b59143acddfc>:0 
  at System.Composition.Hosting.ContainerConfiguration.CreateContainer () [0x00042] in <9aac21a4a3f24063b2b8b59143acddfc>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef.MefHostServices.Create (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] assemblies) [0x0001e] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem.MonoDevelopWorkspace..cctor () [0x001f9] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem/MonoDevelopWorkspace.cs:121 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MonoDevelop.CSharp.ProjectSearchCategory.Init () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/CSharpBinding/MonoDevelop.CSharp/ProjectSearchCategory.cs:53 
  at MonoDevelop.CSharp.Project.CSharpProject.get_TargetRuntime () [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/CSharpBinding/MonoDevelop.CSharp.Project/CSharpProjectExtension.cs:56 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:661 
FATAL ERROR [2017-11-15 08:37:44Z]: Can't create roslyn workspace
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem.MonoDevelopWorkspace' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Type Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.CaseCorrection.VisualBasicCaseCorrectionService has invalid vtable method slot 6 with method none
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.RuntimeType:GetPropertiesByName_native (System.RuntimeType,intptr,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,bool)
  at System.RuntimeType.GetPropertiesByName (System.String name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Boolean icase, System.RuntimeType reflectedType) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:516 
  at System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyCandidates (System.String name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Type[] types, System.Boolean allowPrefixLookup) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:2881 
  at System.RuntimeType.GetProperties (System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:3089 
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetRuntimeProperties (System.Type type) [0x00006] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/RuntimeReflectionExtensions.cs:25 
  at System.Composition.TypedParts.Discovery.TypeInspector+d__7.MoveNext () [0x00030] in <9aac21a4a3f24063b2b8b59143acddfc>:0 
  at System.Composition.TypedParts.Discovery.TypeInspector+d__5.MoveNext () [0x000dc] in <9aac21a4a3f24063b2b8b59143acddfc>:0 
  at System.Composition.TypedParts.Discovery.TypeInspector.InspectTypeForPart (System.Reflection.TypeInfo type, System.Composition.TypedParts.Discovery.DiscoveredPart& part) [0x00061] in <9aac21a4a3f24063b2b8b59143acddfc>:0 
  at System.Composition.TypedParts.TypedPartExportDescriptorProvider..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] types, System.Composition.Convention.AttributedModelProvider attributeContext) [0x00037] in <9aac21a4a3f24063b2b8b59143acddfc>:0 
  at System.Composition.Hosting.ContainerConfiguration.CreateContainer () [0x00042] in <9aac21a4a3f24063b2b8b59143acddfc>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef.MefHostServices.Create (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] assemblies) [0x0001e] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem.MonoDevelopWorkspace..cctor () [0x001f9] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem/MonoDevelopWorkspace.cs:121 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object:__icall_wrapper_mono_generic_class_init (intptr)
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem.TypeSystemService..cctor () [0x0009f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem/TypeSystemService.cs:86

Comment: @SushiHangover - the app IS an Azure Mobile Quickstart App, I created the instance with that name and therefore an example app with that name is generated and can be downloaded from the before mentioned location (under Deployment/Quickstart in that instance). Thanks for the hint with the logs, will look into that.

Comment: Ok, I thought that was an invalid name on an instance... well, check the IDE logs as that should help.

Comment: `Type Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.CaseCorrection.VisualBasicCaseCorrectionService has invalid vtable method slot 6 with method none at (wrapper managed-to-native)` Do you have any 3rd-party Extensions installed/enabled that are Code Analysis and/or VisualBasic related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was MFractor in my case - disabled it and now it works just fine - thanks a ton to @SushiHangover !!!

Comment: What version of MFractor for VS Mac were you using? This issue was fixed in mid-October around MFractor version 3.2.10. If you need a hand, please email me at matthew@mfractor.com

Comment: VS says 3.02.19 - but I had it updated and it works now, so I cannot tell you the original version unless there is a way to see that in a log or somewhere else...